# Array concat is overwriting the values in for..each loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, concatenation

```
const states = ["BR", "UP"];
const template = [
    {
      "State": "",
      "allotment": 25622
    },
    {
      "State": "",
      "expenditure": 1254
    }
  ];

let totalRecords: any[] = [];
states.forEach(state=>{
  const cc = template.map(record=> {record.State = state; return record})
  console.log(state, cc);// here i get the indiviual record set.
  totalRecords = totalRecords.concat(cc);
})
console.log(totalRecords);
```

here i am trying to get a concatenated list of template with different states, but somehow it is overwriting the previous records.
although as seen in the console after adding map to template, a proper record set is seen. still it is not concatenating properly.

how to do it properly as required result is

```
[{
  "State": "BR",
  "allotment": 25622
}, {
  "State": "BR",
  "expenditure": 1254
}, {
  "State": "UP",
  "allotment": 25622
}, {
  "State": "UP",
  "expenditure": 1254
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're *reusing* the objects from `template`, just overwriting the properties of those objects. If you want to have multiple objects for each state, you'll need to create *new* objects instead:

```
const cc = template.map((record) => {
    record = { ...record, State: state }; // ***
    return record;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const states = ["BR", "UP"];
const template = [
    {
        State: "",
        allotment: 25622,
    },
    {
        State: "",
        expenditure: 1254,
    },
];

let totalRecords /*: any[]*/ = [];
states.forEach((state) => {
    const cc = template.map((record) => {
        record = { ...record, State: state };
        return record;
    });
    console.log(state, cc);
    totalRecords = totalRecords.concat(cc);
});
console.log(totalRecords);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flatMap` and `map` for that like this

```js
const states = ["BR", "UP"];
const template = [
    {
      "State": "",
      "allotment": 25622
    },
    {
      "State": "",
      "expenditure": 1254
    }
  ];


const totalRecords =  states.flatMap(State=> template.map(record=> ({...record, State})))

console.log(totalRecords)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your program lies here:
`template.map(record=> {record.State = state; return record})`

You are not returning a new object, you are overwriting a previous one.

Try this:

```
const states = ["BR", "UP"];
const template = [
    {
      "State": "",
      "allotment": 25622
    },
    {
      "State": "",
      "expenditure": 1254
    }
  ];

let totalRecords: any[] = [];
states.forEach(state=>{
  const cc = template.map(record=> ({...record, 'State': state}))
  totalRecords = totalRecords.concat(cc);
})
console.log(totalRecords);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Code:

```js
const states = ['BR', 'UP']
const template = [{State:'',allotment: 25622,},{State:'',expenditure:1254}]

const totalRecords = states.reduce(
  (a, State) => a.concat(template.map((t) => ({ ...t, State }))), 
  []
)

console.log(totalRecords)
```